# Your browser does not support the video tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have IE 11 and Chrome X64 installed.

In this html example code in w3schools.com page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Does not run in IE 11 or Chrome. As you can see it lets me know : Your browser does not support the video tag.

Comment: Your Stack Snippet shows me a video player in Chrome and IE11 ...?

Comment: Please click on Run code snippet. As you can see It is not working.

Comment: As I can see, the snippet doesn't show me "_Your browser does not support the video tag_" text, it shows me a video player, with both mentioned browsers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using video tag and my advice when you embed a video or picture (image) make sure to use the right path. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify compatibility with canIuse.com
But's it's very strange because Chrome supports
 [< video >](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) ...

Else, you have some great video plugins ...

Comment: I've been checking several blogs and web pages and it looks like HTML5 does not support video tag. Am I wrong ?.

Comment: @EnriqueBello Why to search around, you can always read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).